# Execute with one parameter? Why

Tags: c++, linux

After compiling a program with "g++ -o myFile myFile.cpp" I used "./myFile &" to execute the program. When using the ampersand, I understand the program is executing in the background. Can someone direct me to the right link explaining what "./myFile a" means? I don't understand why using command "a" executes one input parameter.

Comment: `./myFile` is the command name, not `a`. `a` is a string that is passed to the program `/myFile` as a command line argument.

Comment: I don't understand your statement "I don't understand why using command "a" executes one input parameter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main function in a C/C++ program is just like any other function.  Since you did not include sample code I'll give two general examples:

```
int main(){}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}
```

In the first case, the main function accepts no parameters, in the second the main function accepts two parameters.  The first (argc) describes the number of arguments from the shell when the program is started:

```
./myFile a
```

Here the value of argc would be 2 (one for the program name './myFile' and one for the parameter 'a').  The second function parameter argv is an array of c-strings and in this case, would contain:

```
argv[0] = "./myFile";
argv[1] = "a";
```

Comment: And `argv[argc] == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not an command. It is the command line arguments.

Command line arguments is the input passed to your program.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
```